# How to fit parameters, not functions?

Tags: numerics, fitting

Given a set of parameters

```
Y1[a1_, b1_, c1_, d1_, e1_, f1_] := 
({{a1, b1, c1},
  {b1, d1, e1},
  {c1, e1, f1}});



Y2[a2_, b2_, c2_, d2_, e2_, f2_] := 
    ({{a2, b2, c2},
      {b2, d2, e2},
      {c2, e2, f2}});
```

and a function

```
MA[kd_, a1_, b1_, c1_, d1_, e1_, f1_, a2_, b2_, c2_, d2_, e2_, f2_,r_,s_] := r*(kd*Y1[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1]+s*Y2[a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2]);

MB[kd_, a1_, b1_, c1_, d1_, e1_, f1_, a2_, b2_, c2_, d2_, e2_, f2_,r_,s_] := r*(kd*Y1[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1]-3s*Y2[a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2]);
```

what is the best way to fit the parameters in Mathematica, such that the Eigenvalues of MA come as close as possible to some given "data":

```
dataA = {171.7, 6.19*10^-1, 1.27*10^-3};
```

and the Eigenvalues of MB as close as possible to

```
dataB = {1.2, 4.22*10^-2, 1.11*10^-4};
```

Comment: For the example here at least, the solution is not unique: off the top of my head, `{a,d,f}=data` and all other parameter=0 is solution.

Comment: All Hermitian matrices are of the form $\mathbf{U}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{U}^H$, where $\mathbf{U}$ is a unitary matrix and $\mathbf{\Lambda}$ is a real diagonal matrix with elements the eigenvalues of the matrix

Comment: @egwenesedai Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, my problem is more complicated like that. I'm interested in methods to solve such problems in general

Comment: To say the same thing as those above, you have 7 parameters you want to fit, but really only three equations.

Comment: @JasonB Yes, but in my actual problem this is not the case, but unfortunately it's to complicated to post here. I'm just trying to find some numerical procedure to find the parameters such that the Eigenvalues come as close as possible to the data

Comment: `r` and `s` are parameters or constants?

Comment: @JasonB r and s are parameters, too. I changed the question accordingly

Comment: @JakobH, can I assume that is a typo, and the second definition of MA is really MB?

Comment: @JasonB Sorry, yes I changed it

Comment: If you are getting responses that are not workable, it is because the posted problem is an oversimplification. Hard to get good responses in that situation (and easy for people to waste their time attacking the wrong problem). I would not be surprised if this one also gets closed.

Answer (score 4):

So you already [found a way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104485/9490) to do this with `NMinimize`, and we can apply that to this problem,

```
Y1[a1_, b1_, c1_, d1_, e1_, 
   f1_] := ({{a1, b1, c1}, {b1, d1, e1}, {c1, e1, f1}});
Y2[a2_, b2_, c2_, d2_, e2_, 
   f2_] := ({{a2, b2, c2}, {b2, d2, e2}, {c2, e2, f2}});
MA = r*(kd*Y1[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1] + 
     s*Y2[a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2]);
MB = r*(kd*Y1[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1] - 
     3 s*Y2[a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2]);
eigenvaluesA = {171.7, 6.19*10^-1, 1.27*10^-3};
eigenvaluesB = {1.2, 4.22*10^-2, 1.11*10^-4};
```

So here we just try to minimize the squared differences between the desired eigenvalues and those found with the parameters,

```
min = Total[(eigenvaluesA - Eigenvalues[MA])^2] + 
   Total[(eigenvaluesB - Eigenvalues[MB])^2];
soln = 
 NMinimize[
  min, {kd, a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2, r, s}]
(* {3.46679*10^-13, {kd -> -4.40918, a1 -> 3.60776, 
  b1 -> 3.12456, c1 -> 3.35833, d1 -> 2.76614, e1 -> 2.94399, 
  f1 -> 3.17628, a2 -> 3.67659, b2 -> 3.18482, c2 -> 3.48571, 
  d2 -> 2.81491, e2 -> 3.05773, f2 -> 3.23996, r -> -3.0766, 
  s -> -1.42852}} *)
```

We can see that the solution gives the desired output with an error of roughly $10^{-7}$:

```
Eigenvalues[MA /. soln[[2]]] - eigenvaluesA
(* {1.19948*10^-7, 4.01605*10^-7, 3.79767*10^-7} *)

Eigenvalues[MB /. soln[[2]]] - eigenvaluesB
(* {3.98774*10^-8, -9.11667*10^-8, 1.29922*10^-7} *)
```

You can get a much lower error by using the following (kludgy) method.  The idea here is to find 2 random symmetric real matrices that have the required eigenvalues, then find values of the parameters for which MA and MB are equal to these matrices.  Problem is, it doesn't always find a solution, but when it does find a solution it finds it pretty quick (giving a warning about the fact that it is choosing one out of an infinite number of solutions).  So I put it in a `While` loop and it hasn't gone more than 7 attempts before finding an answer.  I use `TimeConstrained` because if it will find a solution, it can find it quickly.

```
soln = {};
Monitor[
 attempt = 0;
 While[Length[soln] === 0,
  attempt++;
  utmat = Orthogonalize[RandomReal[1, {3, 3}]];
  newmatA = 
   utmat.DiagonalMatrix[eigenvaluesA].ConjugateTranspose[utmat];
  newmatB = 
   utmat.DiagonalMatrix[eigenvaluesB].ConjugateTranspose[utmat];
  TimeConstrained[
   soln = NSolve[{MA == newmatA, MB == newmatB}, {kd, a1, b1, c1, d1, 
      e1, f1, a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2, r, s}, Reals], 10]
  ], attempt]
soln

(*{{kd -> 0.18126, a1 -> 24.3811, b1 -> 30.6528, c1 -> -14.7131, 
  d1 -> 39.2123, e1 -> -18.7668, f1 -> 8.98672, a2 -> -0.0722954, 
  b2 -> -0.0909739, c2 -> 0.0436602, d2 -> -0.11632, e2 -> 0.0556748, 
  f2 -> -0.0266615, r -> 9.84737, s -> -20.1751}, {kd -> -3.79732, 
  a1 -> -3.24835, b1 -> -4.08394, c1 -> 1.96026, d1 -> -5.22436, 
  e1 -> 2.50035, f1 -> -1.19732, a2 -> -1.84245, b2 -> -2.31848, 
  c2 -> 1.11268, d2 -> -2.96442, e2 -> 1.41888, f2 -> -0.679472, 
  r -> 3.52805, s -> -2.20961}} *)
```

Now the error is 6 orders of magnitude lower,

```
Eigenvalues[MA /. soln[[1]]] - eigenvaluesA
Eigenvalues[MB /. soln[[1]]] - eigenvaluesB
(* {-5.40012*10^-13, -1.15463*10^-14, -9.97162*10^-15} *)
(* {4.72955*10^-13, 1.147*10^-14, 1.15181*10^-14} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, my problem is more complicated and at first I posted my question in a simplified way. I'm more interested in a way to treat such problems in general in mathematica